# Bash escaping spaces in filename, in variable

Tags: bash, escaping, spaces

I'm quite new to Bash so this might be something trivial, but I'm just not getting it. I'm trying to escape the spaces inside filenames. Have a look. Note that this is a 'working example' - I get that interleaving files with blank pages might be accomplished easier, but I'm here about the space.

```
#! /bin/sh

first=true
i=combined.pdf
o=combined2.pdf
for f in test/*.pdf
do
    if $first; then
        first=false
        ifile=\"$f\"
    else
        ifile=$i\ \"$f\"
    fi
    pdftk $ifile blank.pdf cat output $o
    t=$i
    i=$o
    o=$t
    break
done
```

Say I have a file called `my file.pdf` (with a space). I want the ifile variable to contain the string `combined.pdf "my file.pdf"`, such that pdftk is able to use it as two file arguments - the first one being `combined.pdf`, and the second being `my file.pdf`.

I've tried various ways of escaping (with or without first escaping the quotes themselves, etc.), but it keeps splitting `my` and `file.pdf` when executing pdftk.

EDIT: To clarify: I'm trying to pass multiple file names (as multiple arguments) in one variable to the pdftk command. I would like it to recognise the difference between two file names, but not tear one file name apart at the spaces.

Comment: Not to being annoying but two seconds of googling and I found this: http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2011/combining-pdf-files-with-pdftk

Comment: This is a 'minimal working example' of my issue, though. I'm doing a few other things before appending the files.

Comment: Ah because you you need a blank page between each page. I did not see that.

Comment: Why are you getting so complicated? Use 2 variables: `pdftk "$i" "$f" ...`

Comment: @AdamGent - thanks for the pointer to lornajane.net/posts/2011/combining-pdf-files-with-pdftk - I learnt something new with the -J option to xargs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Putting multiple arguments into a single variable doesn't make sense. Instead, put them into an array:

```
args=(combined.pdf "my file.pdf");
```

Notice that `"my file.pdf"` is quoted to preserve whitespace.

You can use the array like this:

```
pdftk "${args[@]}" ...
```

This will pass two separate arguments to `pdftk`. The quotes in `"${args[@]}"` are required because they tell the shell to treat each array element as a separate "word" (i.e. do not split array elements, even if they contain whitespace).

As a side note, if you use `bash`isms like arrays, change your shebang to

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that will not work correctly if the file has spaces in it. I remember having issues doing something like that once.

Comment: This is what I should've started doing right from the start. It's nonsense to try to use a string for this. Thanks!

Comment: @AdamGent From the `bash` manpage section on arrays: `If the word
is double-quoted,...${name[@]} expands each element of name to a separate word.` In other words, array elements are *not* split on whitespace.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I don't recall the exact issue but I believe it was an issue with a new line character in the file name. I had to use a null separator ala find/xargs combo.

Comment: The problem of `xargs` parsing the output from `find` is a different problem from quoting whitespace to prevent the shell from performing word-splitting on it.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
find test/*.pdf | xargs -I % pdftk % cat output all.pdf
```

As I said in my comments on other answers `xargs` is the most efficient way to do this.

EDIT: I did not see you needed a blank page but I suppose you could pipe the `find` above to some command to put the blank page between (similar to a list->string join). I prefer this way as its more FP like.

Comment: You're not escaping the spaces. This should be `find test/*.pdf -print0 | xargs -0 -J % pdftk % cat output all.pdf`